# Replace function is not working as I needed, Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using replace function to change panda data-frame column values 0 for the forward value of the column, but value are not being replaced, Can somebody correct my mistake?

```py
df[B] = 0.0
conditions = [
    (df[A] >= 70),
    (df[A] <= 30)]
choices = [-1,1]
df[B] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=0)

df[B].replace(to_replace=0, method='ffill')
```

```
Expected:

2019-05-17 75.585587 -1

2019-05-20 42.072757 -1

2019-05-21 47.518097 -1

2019-05-22 25.958243 1

2019-05-23 40.008826 1

2019-05-24 40.933200 1

2019-05-28 37.116863 1


Actual:

2019-05-17 75.585587 -1

2019-05-20 42.072757 0

2019-05-21 47.518097 0

2019-05-22 25.958243 1

2019-05-23 40.008826 0

2019-05-24 40.933200 0

2019-05-28 37.116863 0
```

Comment: Thanks "Vishwas" for the text corrections!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is fine as far as the functionality is concerned, you are just missing the `inplace = True` argument in you `df[B].replace` function call. You should do some thing like below to retain the results of replace.

```
df[B].replace(to_replace=0, method='ffill', inplace= True)
```

or

```
df[B] = df[B].replace(to_replace=0, method='ffill')
```

Hope this helps,

Cheers

Comment: You are welcome :) and if my answer was helpful, I would really appreciate if you can accept it.